# fetch custom post if meta key exist

Tags: forms

I have some custom post and I am trying to fetch data if meta key value is exist .
I have a Html form and I am  trying to fetch post  by arrive and depart time .
Here is my form .

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-md-2" id="bgform_text2">
                        <h4>SEARCH</h4>
                        <p>For Your Favourite Place</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-md-2">
                        <label>Where to ? </label>
                        <input  type="text" name="names" class="input-text full-width" placeholder="start typing here....">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-md-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <label>Arrive </label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" name="arive_time" id="departing">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <label>Departs </label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" name="depart_time" id="returning">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-9 col-md-2">
                        <label>Sleeps </label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>
                                                        <select name="sleep">
                          <option value="" disabled="" selected=""></option>
                          <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></option>
                        </select>

                      </div> 

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-md-2">
                        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit_btn" class="button">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is my php code .Problem is that I am  too confused how can i fetch post by meta key value .when form is submit.

```
 <?php

                $args = array(
                'post_type'         => 'mad_property',
                 'post_status'       => 'publish',
                 'paged'             => '-1',   
            // 'meta_query'        => $meta_query,
        );



        $prop_selection = new WP_Query($args);
        if( $prop_selection->have_posts() ){
            $count=0;               
            while ($prop_selection->have_posts()): $prop_selection->the_post(); 
                $count++;
                if($count > 9){
                    print '<div class="property_search_hidden" style="display:none;opacity:0;">';
                }
                // if( wpestate_check_booking_valability($book_from,$book_to,$post->ID) ){
                    get_template_part('templates/property_unit');
                if($count > 3){
                    print '</div>';
                }
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_query();
            $s='';
            if($count > 1){
                $s = 's';
            }
            print '<div class="search_notice"><h3>We found '.$count.' item'.$s.' for you!</h3></div>';
            if($count > 3){                 
                print '<div class="col-md-12 show_more_saps"><button onclick="show_hidden_property();" class="btn btn-large btn-saps">Show all '.$count.' property were found</button></div>';
            }
        }else{
            print '<span class="no_results">'. esc_html__( "We didn't find any results","wpestate").'</span>';
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track: use a [meta_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) in your query.

There are plenty of examples in the codex, how you implement it depends on what fields you're using, but that's the way to go. An example with multiple fields queried:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'color',
            'value'   => 'blue',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'price',
            'value'   => array( 20, 100 ),
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```